# how to reload the contents of fragment when tab is reselected in fragmenttabhost android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, fragment-tab-host

I am creating a tabhost in fragment activity .And I have created a fragment which dynamically loads the contents for each tab when tab is selected. I am using asynctask to load the contents of tab. As I am loading the contents of tab when it is selected I have created single  fragment as content for tab. Also my tabs are created dynamically.

My question is when I select any tab for the first time the contents are loaded by executing the asynctask,but when I select the tab which was selected earlier the content does not change, rather the contents of the initial tab which was selected for the first time are displayed.

this is onCreateView method in the fragment whee the contents are being loaded when the tab is selected :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container, false); 

        return rootView;
    }
```

this is onActivityCreated method where I am calling asynctask

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            new FetchMenuTask().execute();


    }
```

what should i do to change the contents when tab is reselected

Answer (score -1):

You should put your asyntask method in onCreateView().
Then each time fragment is select (add/replace), your asynctask will be called within onCreateView(), then you can update view with new data at onPostExecute().

Comment: This does not work. I tried calling asynctask in onCreateView method.

Comment: You should put Log at every Fragment's lifecycle to make sure which one is called each time you reselect subtab. Then put the AsynTask.execute() there.